# CSS: Width problems

Tags: css, width

I've got a list item with an image inside, for example:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img></img>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The image does not take up the full width of the li.

How can I get the li width to shrink to the size of its containing image?

Comment: The ul has a set width...if this has anything to do with it...??

Comment: show your code in jsfiddle.net for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the height of images

```
   <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="" width="xxx" height="xxx"></img>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

### Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/CZqEc/

updated live demo http://jsfiddle.net/CZqEc/1/

Comment: Is it possible to get the li to shrink dynamically though?

Answer (score 0):

If you set your li to `display: inline`, since li are blocks by default, the width would match the largest/widest element.

Answer (score 0):

If `<li>` is `display:block` or similar (`list-item` also)

use `li img{max-width:100%}`

---

If `<li>` is `display:inline-block` or `display:inline`
you also need to set `<li>` width

Answer (score 0):

or try

```
li
{
background:url('');
display:   ;
background-size:xx xx;
}
```